# Copy not working sometimes on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, clipboard

I often have this peculiar problem with copying things where pressing ctrl+c or selecting text and clicking copy doesn't actually copy the image/text to my clipboard. Instead the clipboard isn't updated and the thing I last copied remains in the clipboard. This happens on all programs.
I found that this issue disappears once I click and copy my browser's URL bar (using Firefox), only to reappear after an hour or two.

Has anyone run into this issue or has any suggestions how can I debug this?

Comment: You should start by making sure the system is fully updated. A 20.04 should report as 20.04.4, not 3.

Comment: Got a similar problem, really annoying, in my case : you copy text, but if you do special blank characters suppression, it sometimes changes the buffer and you paste some blank characters... I first though it was Intellij, but no it's Ubuntu, the problem exist since at least one year. My system is always up to date in LTS.

Comment: Fully updating fixed the problem for me, but I still encounter this once a month or so and then the browser trick sorts it out for me.

Comment: I face the same _copy_ problem from time to time in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, MATE 1.24.0. But I have **ClipIt** installed and I click it's icon at the panel (once or twice) and I select the latest copied text or whatever.